# JMS setRollbackOnly - inconsistent behaviour

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean

Please have a look at the following Message Driver Bean.
The message comes in, we call `clearProperties()` on it to unlock and be able set some other properties on it.
At the end we call `setRollbackOnly()` on the `MessageDrivenContext` so that the message will be re-delivered.

We use ActiveMQ as a message broker with JBoss and the corresponding `activemq-rar.rar` resource adapter.
There is a difference although between recent and new releases on how this resource adapter behaves regarding the code segment below.
Until version "5.11.0.redhat-630446" of the resource adapter, the `property("newprop")` we set in the `onMessage` method appeared in the message that has been re-delivered.
Since version "5.11.0.redhat-630475" the `clearProperties()` and `setObjectProperty()` method has no effect on the re-delivered message, so it falls in the `onMessage` method with the same properties as the original 1st message.

I wonder which is the right behaviour?

```java
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/QUEUE1"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})

public class MDBean implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext contextMD;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            message.clearProperties();
            message.setObjectProperty("newprop", "newprop");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        contextMD.setRollbackOnly();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing with the newer version is the correct one. The relevant change was made via [AMQ-7464](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7464). In short, changes made to the message during consumption should **not** be reflected in the message during redelivery.